# Replace (one or) two different patterns in a file with regexp

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl, ripgrep

Suppose an `input.txt` file that contains several strings as the following ones:

```
[[foo>a|a]]
[[foo>b|b]]
[[foo>c|c]]
```

that I'd like to replace by:

```
:foo:`a`
:foo:`b`
:foo:`c`
```

I guess I could manage to achieve this result with `sed` or `rg` (I never used `awk`).

But this file also contains other strings as the following ones:

```
[[foo>a|d]]
[[foo>b|e]]
[[foo>c|f]]
```

that I'd like to replace by:

```
:foo:`d <a>`
:foo:`e <b> `
:foo:`f <c>`
```

All my attempts failed because I don't see how to handle two different patterns at once.

Do you know some ways to achieve the latter result (and, BTW, the former)?

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to handle both at once?  Why not handle them separately?  That would make it easier to understand and to maintain.

Comment: Indeed, I badly explained myself. I wanted to express I didn't know how to handle two patterns. The answers below gave me the hint (`$1`, `$2`, etc. with Perl, `\1`, `\2`,  with sed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lookarounds, you can check if the strings around `|` are same or not. For example:

```bsh
$ cat ip.txt 
[[foo>a|d]]
[[foo>b|e]]
[[foo>c|f]]

# same as: rg -NP '\[\[([^>]+)>([^|]+)\|(?!\2])([^|]+)]]' -r ':$1:`$3 <$2>`'
$ perl -pe 's/\[\[([^>]+)>([^|]+)\|(?!\2])([^|]+)]]/:$1:`$3 <$2>`/' ip.txt 
:foo:`d <a>`
:foo:`e <b>`
:foo:`f <c>`
```

`(?!\2])` is a negative lookahead assertion to ensure that the strings around `|` are different.

To implement both, you can make use of Perl code in replacement section with `e` flag.

```bsh
$ cat ip.txt
[[foo>a|a]]
[[foo>b|b]]
[[foo>c|c]]

[[foo>a|d]]
[[foo>b|e]]
[[foo>c|f]]

$ perl -pe 's/\[\[([^>]+)>([^|]+)\|([^|]+)]]/":$1:`$3" . ($2 eq $3 ? "`" : " <$2>`")/e' ip.txt 
:foo:`a`
:foo:`b`
:foo:`c`

:foo:`d <a>`
:foo:`e <b>`
:foo:`f <c>`
```

Here, `` ($2 eq $3 ? "`" : " <$2>`") `` will choose the string depending on whether the strings around `|` are same or not.

Answer (score 3):

With standard `sed`  syntax:

```bsh
sed '
  s/^\[\[\(.*\)>\(.*\)|\2\]\]$/:\1:`\2`/; t
  s/^\[\[\(.*\)>\(.*\)|\(.*\)\]\]$/:\1:`\3 <\2>`/'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we could split this task to 2-3 separated parts. First we squeeze (`-s`) and replace some characters with `tr`, to create the "outline" of the output, and then with a `sed` we make two separate replacements, one for the two characters matching and one for when they are different.

```
< file tr -s '[<>|]' ':::``' | sed -E 's/(.)`\1`/`\1`/; s/([^:])`(.)`/`\2 <\1>`/'
```

Testing:

```
$ cat file
[[foo>a|a]]
[[foo>b|b]]
[[foo>c|c]]
[[foo>a|d]]
[[foo>b|e]]
[[foo>c|f]]

$ <file tr -s '[<>|]' ':::``' | sed -E 's/(.)`\1`/`\1`/;s/([^:])`(.)`/`\2 <\1>`/' 
:foo:`a`
:foo:`b`
:foo:`c`
:foo:`d <a>`
:foo:`e <b>`
:foo:`f <c>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` to manage to handle both your given formats:

```
awk -F'\\[\\[|\\]\\]|>|\\|' '{
    print $1, $2, "`" ($3==$4? $3 : $4" <"$3">") "`";
}' OFS=':' infile
```

Test input:

```
[[foo>a|a]]
[[foo>bb|bb]]
[[foo>c|ccc]]
[[foo>aaaa|d]]
[[foo>b|ddd]]
[[foo>cccc|fff]]
```

Output:

```
:foo:`a`
:foo:`bb`
:foo:`ccc <c>`
:foo:`d <aaaa>`
:foo:`ddd <b>`
:foo:`fff <cccc>`
```